# CPU Mining Test with CGminer

Tags: cgminer, cpu, cpuminer

After my boss read the websites mining on visits he got the idea to use the entire network we have access to. I have access to 3000+ computers and have been give permission to run a test over the weekend. Some of these computers have GPU's some don't. I would like to run cgminer with the --enable-cpumining flag to allow the cpu to work on the computers without GPU's.

when I use the tag

```
--enable-cpumining
```

I get

```
--enable-cpumining: unrecognized option
```

I think I am missing something here, any help would be great.

Comment: What currency are you planning to mine?  Most of the major ones are not feasible to mine with GPU, much less CPU.  You will spend lots on electricity and earn nothing.  Save your time and tell your boss it's a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Q: What happened to CPU and GPU mining?

A: Their efficiency makes them irrelevant in the bitcoin mining world today

and the author has no interest in supporting alternative coins that are better

mined by these devices

from https://github.com/ckolivas/cgminer/blob/master/README

Comment: What relevance does this have to the question?

Comment: it's from their documentation, they removed the option he's trying to use, that's why he get's the error @MeshCollider